# Selecting UIView programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my application, I want to select `UIView` programmatically.
How can I select `UIView` programmatically?

```
If(UIView is selected programmatically || UIView is tapped){

          invoke tapGesture Action
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by select the view? Change the color of the view or highlight it in some way?

Comment: I mean I want to tap the UIView Programatically

Comment: When a view is tapped, a method gets called as the action of the target.  There's nothing preventing you from calling that method programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView itself doesn't support selection, although some subclasses do. For example, UITableViewCell has a `selected` property that modifies how the cell draws itself.

If you want to mimic what happens when a user taps a view, you'll do two things:

- Provide the same feedback that the user would see if she tapped that view. This might mean redrawing the view, performing an animation,playing a sound, or some combination of those.
- Perform the same action that would happen if the user tapped the view.

So, if the view is a button, you might set its `highlighted` state to YES, wait maybe 0.2 seconds, and then set it back to its previous state. Next, invoke the button's action on the button's target.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(aMethodToBeCalled)];
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
```

implement the `aMethodToBeCalled` method and do whatever needs to be called there.

Comment: I want to select UIView programatically as well and want to invoke same method "aMethodToBeCalled"

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "select UIView"

Comment: I mean I want to tap the UIView Programatically

Comment: That's what the UITapGestureRecognizer is for - it gives you the ability to associate the tap gesture with a method to be invoked when this happens.

Comment: I want it to be happened automatically. I mean I want a UIView to be tapped automatically when an event occurs.

Comment: Yeah I'm not following either. Multitouch UI depends on the user tapping something. This is where gestures come in. If you want to highlight the view when something happens that's a different story. What you're really looking for is handling this event that you describe. The above code is handling a tap event.

Comment: Sorry, @IdreesAshraf - your question is very unclear. Please find a different way of describing what you need otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: @IdreesAshraf: I think what you wanted to do is invoking the method that when tapping of a UIView occurred?  If so, all you need is just invoking that method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to select the subviews.

You could tag the view on initialization with:

```
UIView *exampleView = [UIView alloc] init];
[exampleView setTag:1];
```

Add the view:

```
[self.view addSubView:exampleView];
```

When you want to call the view, just use:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```